# wxWidgets installed with incorrect header path

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, ubuntu-18.04

I just installed wxWidgets on Ubuntu 18.04 for C++ using the instructions from the following URL: https://www.binarytides.com/install-wxwidgets-ubuntu/

The installation was successful, but instead of calling the header file as `#include <wx/wx.h>` I have to call for it as `#include <wx-3.1/wx/wx.h>` which is leading to issues inside additional header files that also call for `<wx/wx.h>`

Is there any way I can remove the 'wx-3.1' without reinstalling or will I have to go in the header files and add this prefix each time this is called?

Comment: "instead of calling the header file" - You mean to say "instead of including the header file". One does not *call* header files.

Comment: Your build system should have a way to specify the wx-3.1 directory as an additional include directory.  (-I) on the gcc command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers are installed correctly, you're just not using the correct path to include them. You must use `wx-config` to get the flags for compiling and linking your programs, e.g. your compile command should look like

```
g++ -c `wx-config --cxxflags` foo.cpp
```

and your link command should look like

```
g++ -o foo foo.o `wx-config --libs`
```

If you do it like this, everything should work just as you expect.

P.S. This has nothing to do with your question, but I wish I knew why people decide following instructions on some random 4.5 year old blog post instead of the official build instructions in the manual (or `docs/gtk/install.md` for Real Programmers who don't read the manuals). This post at least looks correct (after a brief look), but this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should install wxWidgets the same way as you did install the compier and GTK.

I.e.

```
sudo apt-get install wxgtk wxgtk-devel
```

it will install prebuilt and packaged wxWidgets so that it will be ready for development.

If you want to compile from sources - make sure you can successfully build `minimal sample` as explained in the link referenced.